# How to swipe a ListView row in Android?

Tags: android, listview, swipe

I am a newbie in Android. I have generated a Listview using `SimpleAdapter`. The ListView  displays 3 textviews in a row. I want to add one more textview and keep it hidden until the user swipes the Listview row i.e when the user swipes all the 4 textviews should be visible. Can anyone suggest me how to do it. any links or tutorial will be helpful.

Comment: You can use this library - https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Comment: @user3509091 could you elaborate your question? I believe we all have a misunderstanding about what you want. Or is it just me?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [design pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html) and [how to implement it](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html), both from developer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is a fixed height ListView. Apply the `layout_weight` property to control the height of the ListView and other objects. I guess there are other objects below the ListView otherwise you wouldn't want it to have a fixed height.

Comment: k..There are altogether 4 textviews in my row. What I want to do is hide the textview to the left initially. I want the hidden textview to be visible only when the user swipes i.e now altogether all 4 textviews should be visible. –

Answer (score 0):

1st: you have to create your own custom list view.

2nd: use this

```
    navigaList.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
navigaList.setOnItemClickListener(listener);

OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                            long arg3) {
        if(swipeDetector.swipeDetected()) {
            if(swipeDetector.getAction() == Action.RL) {

            } else {

            }
        }        
    };
```

then you have to detect swipe by using this class

```
public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

public static enum Action {
    LR, // Left to Right
    RL, // Right to Left
    TB, // Top to bottom
    BT, // Bottom to Top
    None // when no action was detected
}

private static final String logTag = "SwipeDetector";
private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
private Action mSwipeDetected = Action.None;

public boolean swipeDetected() {
    return mSwipeDetected != Action.None;
}

public Action getAction() {
    return mSwipeDetected;
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        downX = event.getX();
        downY = event.getY();
        mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
        return false; // allow other events like Click to be processed
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        upX = event.getX();
        upY = event.getY();

        float deltaX = downX - upX;
        float deltaY = downY - upY;

        // horizontal swipe detection
        if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
            // left or right
            if (deltaX < 0) {
                Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Left to Right");
                mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                return true;
            }
            if (deltaX > 0) {
                Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Right to Left");
                mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
                return true;
            }
        } else 

            // vertical swipe detection
            if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                // top or down
                if (deltaY < 0) {
                    Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Top to Bottom");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.TB;
                    return false;
                }
                if (deltaY > 0) {
                    Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Bottom to Top");
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.BT;
                    return false;
                }
            } 
        return true;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

hope this will help you :)

and you may read this:
[here](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview)